# Why TypeScript can't infer the type and still consider this property as null, after filtering for that property?

Tags: typescript

I'm checking with different TypeScript version. TypeScript surprise me a lot of time on how much is smart, but this...?

```ts
type Product = { id: number, imageUrl: null | string };
const products: Product[] = [
  { id: 1, imageUrl: 'assets/img/1.jpg' },
  { id: 2, imageUrl: null }
];

products.filter(p => null !== p.imageUrl).forEach(p => {
  p.imageUrl; // null | string
});
```

Am I'm doing something wrong or it's just a limitation of the language?

Comment: No, you are not doing anything wrong, but static code analysis just doesn't go that far ...

Comment: `{ id: 2 }`  here the image url is not `null`. becomes `undefined` so `null !== p.imageUrl` not `true`, remember `null` and `undefined` are not the same. ts compiler should show error in this case.

Comment: @SalimBaskoy thanks, it's just a typo, i'll fix it.

Comment: `!` with this flag you can clearly indicate that it is a `string`.  will be `p.imageUrl! // string `  string. [try](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=4&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwoF4oG8oCWSAXFAHYoC2ARhHADSGUCGA5hAKpwA2pF33KAB8oAZ2BwCZVlAC+AbgBQaBGXFQwiVBlGl4ydMADaAXWxQjiqHkIkoARkYEW7LrygByZqNERgogHpnVgD7ADoAKzBWDzl6KxsiUgAmJxdOHj4UATlFEyVFTQMdMIAzAm5gOgAKMGwAPnJswQBCLBwwMOc2DO4ASjKEOABRZjQAC1qGvASVNQRuCDDuBFZarvS3Fr6AgLEJKVZFWT75IA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently a limitation of the language. There are however some open issues in GitHub if you want to follow them: [#38390](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38390), [#16069](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069)
You can add a type guard and it should work (as suggested in the referenced issues):

```js
type Product = { id: number, imageUrl: null | string };
const products: Product[] = [
  { id: 1, imageUrl: 'assets/img/1.jpg' },
  { id: 2, imageUrl: null }
];

products.filter((p): p is {id: number, imageUrl: string } => null !== p.imageUrl).forEach(p => {
  p.imageUrl; // string
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem so wrong? Before filtering I'm just saying: look that imageUrl is a string for p?

Comment: Yes basically. We are turning the filter function into a type guard returning a type predicate. You can read more about this in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Comment: @gremo it's not *before* filtering, that annotation is the *return type of the callback* and is an assertion to the compiler that the boolean indicates that something passing the predicate has a certain type. Note that this is not any more type-safe than a cast, not that it matters here. The underlying problem is that the return type of `.filter` ordinarily is `T[] => T[]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a limitation of the language, but a simple common solution is to use the `is` syntax to convey this information downstream

```
products
  .map(
    (p: Product) => p.imageUrl
  )
  .filter(
    (imageUrl: string | null): imageUrl is string => !!imageUrl
  )
  .forEach(
    (imageUrl: string) => {
      imageUrl; // string
    }
  );
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwoF4oG8oCWSAXFAHYoC2ARhHADSGUCGA5hAKpwA2pF33KAB8oAZ2BwCZVlAC+AbgBQaBGXFQwiVBlGl4ydMADaAXWxQjiqHkIkoARkYEW7LrygByZqNERgogHpnVgD7ADoAKzBWDzl6KxsiUgAmJxdOHj4UATlFEyVFTQMdBLCWMAAKBOsKsD0tQwBKbAA+DTDnNgzuBMbSgDMCbmA6KusaztdMsQkpGRF+bkbSSe7CURnJaVaoAEJd1bdegYQ4AFFmNAALMfGKw+nxLdZmrDbcavGH7nkoAIDNnNPrJevIgA)

Comment: There is no need to use a cast here.

Comment: I mean, the need is that TypeScript cannot pass this information on to the next array operation from the filter function. There is no "need" to use a Type guard anywhere, it's just one possible tool to assist in narrowing where TypeScript is unable to handle it for us

Comment: "TypeScript cannot pass this information on to the next array operation from the filter function" yes that's true, but there's no need (given the OPs code) to do the filter instead of null-checking inside the forEach. See my answer.

Comment: Agreed :) I was just highlighting/addressing the deficiency of the filter function with this example, which I believe is what the title of the question implied. I agree your solution is simpler though

Comment: @nate-kumar I don't want to map. I need to filter because I'll print other product information in the JSX.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those times you have to work *with* the language:

```
type Product = { id: number, imageUrl: null | string };
const products: Product[] = [
  { id: 1, imageUrl: 'assets/img/1.jpg' },
  { id: 2, imageUrl: null }
];

products.forEach(p => {
  if (p.imageUrl) {
    // here the typechecker knows it's not null
  }
});
```

Note that this is also a more efficient iteration, although that might not matter in your case.

The problem with your original is that `filter` is a function from `T[] => T[]`, not a function from `T[] => SomeSubsetOfTTheCompilerKnowsYouNullChecked[]`.

The compiler can tell in a given scope/block if an access has been checked, and can even do this (in more recent versions) if there's an error path:

```
function f(x: null | string) {
  if (x === null) {
    throw new Error('oops');
  }

  x.repeat(3); // safe!
}
```

...but it can't do this across function calls:

```
function g(x: null | string) {
  return x;
}

const maybeString = Math.round(Math.random()) ? 'hi' : null;
if (maybeString) {
    const a = g(maybeString); // type is still null | string!
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=21&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwoF4oG8oCWSAXFAHYoC2ARhHADSGUCGA5hAKpwA2pF33KAB8oAZ2BwCZVlAC+AbgCwAKDQIy4qGESoMo0vGTpgAbQC62KCZVQ8hElACMjAi3ZdeUAOTNRoiMCiAPSurEGOAHQAVmCsXnL0NnZEpABMLm6cPHwoAnIqZkrKKtpGehEAZghwAKLMaAAWABRg2AB8eEkEFVAtEa5sWdwAlJ3KtrZg-ZkeEdwQ0sAN8lBBQVD1aBB+UGjMZF6YFcwE3EmyKrLDRSoVKGQYBOpQFU0AHjl5IuKS0qO4XR672wWBw-BGYwmUCWiAA7uQIPCanBEHAml4EAgwKIvNdziokm8InAIJBmMAmgBma6rdaiZgVCAAQkuBOUdwewCeZCgrHen0E3wkUlY-ySJOAKDgPLeRQuxVU6k0LBAtAAysLpJYALLkhrEhD3JBNXVLYn7JAIShNYajAD83gaBHiAqK3V6KvVmtFkImag0mGYlj5nogGt+opWa2h4GgBFEYi5eXBwkTEZZynlQA)